# Timed Insert operation in PostgreSQL with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am creating a hostel booking API, i am still figuring it out bit by bit.
Currently there are different room types and they have a quantity, when a room is booked(it has a check-in and check-out date) the quantity drops by 1, how do i go about the logic for adding +1 to that room type when the check-out date has passed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using the Express framework and the Sequelize ORM.

Comment: If you have specific checkout time say 12 P.M. then what you can do is, schedule a cron @ 12:00:01 PM and find all the expired room bookings and add the inventory again. for cron use systems schedulers(recommended) or some node module.